# Regular expression for string Starting with Alphabet and have a space after alphabet

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need a regular expression to do the following

example: `string checker=" A Cat has catched the mouse"`

The regular expression should ensure that the first character should be an alpha character A-D and should have a space after it.

I have tried the regular expression `@"^[A]"` but it also matches with the string below:

`string checker="At the speed of blah blah blah"`

So this regular expression is not giving me what I need.

Comment: Regex won't catch grammar; "A Cat has *caught* the mouse" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this expression

```
@"^[A-D]\s"
```

If you need to capture the whole text, you should do

```
@"^[A-D]\s.*"
```

Comment: and if need double space then the expression should be   like this?           `@"^[A-D]\s\s.*"` @Claudio Redi

Answer (score 2):

Pattern: `^[A-D] .*` (i.e. `string pattern = @"^[A-D] .*"`) will match string that starts with one of the letter from capital `A`, `B`, `C` or `D` and is followed by space.

**Note:** if you are doing just validation you can omit `.*` (i.e. use `^[A-D]` (`string pattern = @"^[A-D] "`) pattern) part from pattern.

Comment: I suggest in addition to trim leading spaces using: checker = checker.TrimStart()

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this help `^([A-D] )`

```
var checkers = new string[] {"At the speed of blah blah blah", "A the speed of blah blah blah", "B the speed of blah blah blah",
                            "C the speed of blah blah blah", "D the speed of blah blah blah", "Dt the speed of blah blah blah",
                            "E the speed of blah blah blah"};

var regex = @"^([A-D] )";

foreach (var checker in checkers)
{
    var matches = Regex.Match(checker, regex);
    Console.WriteLine (matches.Success);
}
```

output:

```
False
True
True
True
True
False
False
```